# Title bar icon not showing

Tags: android

Title bar not icon showing in small screen.when I am running the same application in small and big emulator in big emulator title bar icon but in small not showing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system decides that for you. You have no control over that "Overflow button". According to the [Compatibility Section of the Android Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html):

> "...the action overflow is available from the menu hardware key. The resulting actions popup... is displayed at the bottom of the screen."

Some more reading: http://www.tested.com/tech/android/3510-the-android-40-menu-button-controversy-its-action-overflow-now/